# What is the best way to save ssh output into a struct in golang?

Tags: go

I'm trying to save output of running some commands on other machine with SSH, into a struct.
I used **CombinedOutput** to save the output. Something like this:

```
...
combo, err := session.CombinedOutput("hostname;pwd")
outputResult = string(combo)
...
```

It gives me a 2-line output. I want to save these lines into the below struct:

```
type Result struct {
    Hostname string `json:"hostname"`
    PWD      string `json:"pwd"`
}
```

What is the best (and easy) way to do that? Thanks.

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) has a section about: "Help others reproduce the problem", so please share complete minimal reproducible code.

Comment: So you have bytes of text and you want to split on `\n` newline character to create two separate strings.  Where the string came from (ssh, etc) isn't relevant.

Comment: @Luuk Thanks for the link. It was my first question ever on stackoverflow and I thought the less is better

Comment: @DanielFarrell Yes it's not SSH related; the problem blinded me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It gives me a 2-line output. I want to save these lines into the below struct

Your question really has nothing to do with SSH. You have a `[]byte` that represents the output of your commands.  You want to split it into two strings.

[`strings.SplitN`](https://pkg.go.dev/strings#SplitN) is the perfect solution for this.  You pass it the original string (to which the `[]byte` must be converted), the separator (`\n` in your case), and the maximum number of strings to return.  For us, we want at most 2 strings.  How could there be more than one `\n`?  `pwd` returns a directory, and directories can have newlines in their names, though they very rarely do in practice.

```
    out := []byte("myhost\n/dir")
    fmt.Println(string(out))
    strs := strings.SplitN(string(out), "\n", 2)
    res := Result{Hostname: strs[0], PWD: strs[1]}
```

```
    out := []byte("myhost\n/dir")
    fmt.Println(string(out))
    strs := strings.SplitN(string(out), "\n", 2)
    res := Result{Hostname: strs[0], PWD: strs[1]}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/5ENSgAPg3ER

> ```
> combo, err := session.CombinedOutput("hostname;pwd")
> ```

Remember that this will also include the `stderr` in addition to the `stdout`.  I can't think of a situation where either command would generate any output to `stderr`, but keep in mind that you're not distinguishing between the two.  Hopefully you're checking the result of `err` and if not `nil`, not consuming the results of the command.  That should protect you from unanticipated results from the combination of stdout and stderr.  If stderr is never relevant for you, you might want to use [`ssh.Session.Output`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/crypto/ssh#Session.Output) instead

Comment: I really appreciate your help and also your other points on SSH.